# Invariant subspaces of $T$ and $STS^{-1}$

Tags: linear-algebra

The problem is: Let $S,T\in\mathcal{L}(V)$ and suppose $S$ is invertible. How are the subspaces of $V$ invariant under $T$ related to the subspaces invariant under $STS^{-1}$?

My guess is that: A subspace is invariant under $T$ if and only if it is invariant under $STS^{-1}$. But I failed to prove it.

My attempt at the "only if" direction: Assume that $U$ is an invariant subspace under $T$. Take $u\in U$, $Tu\subseteq U$. $(STS^{-1})(u) = S(T(S^{-1}(u)))$, and I stuck. Since $S$ might not be invariant under $U$, $S^{-1}(u)$ may not belong to $U$, and $T(S^{-1}(u))$ may not belong to $U$...

My question is: Is my guess about the relationship right and if it is, how to prove it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, your guess is not right.

*Hint*. Consider $(STS^{-1})(Su)$.